# How to detect when "ABC" button is tapped on uikeyboard type "UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation"

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uikeyboard

I want to detect when "ABC" button is tapped on uikeyboard type "UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation" as well as i want to detect when "123" button is tapped on alphabetic keyboard type.

I am having "UITextview" control

Pls let me and thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you don't want to replace numbers you want to detect is the following button is pressed?

[image: iOS email keyboard]

If so, as far as I'm aware it's not officially possible. Apple doesn't provide a 'UIKeyboardTypeDidChange' notifications, and you can't edit / alter the Keyboard view while staying within guidelines. Likely your application would get reject if you tried.

(This isn't to say it wouldn't be possible if you hacked away at the Keyboard View).

Answer (score 1):

## - This code allow only numbers in textview

If you are targeting iOS 4.1 and later, you can use UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad. If you need to support older versions, require a decimal point, and don't want anything else, you will have to create a custom keyboard.

If you want to filter out the other keys without removing them, assign some object as the text field's delegate. That object should contain the following code:

```
    - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
       NSCharacterSet *nonNumberSet = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."] invertedSet];
    return([text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:nonNumberSet].length > 0)
    //or
     NSRange location = [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:nonNumberSet];
        return (location.location == NSNotFound);
    }
```

for alphabet and others you use above code with this like code ^[0-9a-zA-Z].I think it is useful for you. have a grate day

Answer (score -1):

use - (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView of textView's delegate protocol. This should solve your problem.